# difference between readlines() and split() [python]

Tags: python, readfile

imagine we have a `file = open("filetext.txt", 'r')`

what is the difference between the split() method and the readlines() method 
It seems that both split each line and put it as a string in a list. 
so what makes them different ?

```
for line in file:
    values = line.split()     #break each line into a list

file.readlines()  #return a list of strings each represent a single line in the file
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`readlines` splits the entire file into lines and is nearly equivalent to `file.read().split('\n')`, except that the latter will remove new lines, whereas `readlines` by itself will retain new lines.

Your example,

```
for line in file:
    values = line.split()
```

splits each line by its spaces, building a list of words in the line. `value` is overwritten on each iteration so unless you save values somewhere, only parts of the file are in-memory at a single time.

Answer (score 1):

This is the main difference:

A [`file`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) object has [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) but not `split`:

```
>>> print hasattr(file, 'split')
False
>>> print hasattr(file, 'readlines')
True
```

A [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) object has [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) but not `readlines`:

```
>>> hasattr("somestring", 'split')
True
>>> hasattr("somestring", 'readlines')
False
```

And to answer your question, one is operating on a string object and one is operating on a file object.

They don't do the same thing since one returns a list of lines when operating on a file and one returns a split line when operating on a string.

Comment: Also, [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=readlines#distutils.text_file.TextFile.readlines) doesn't take arguments and can only break on newlines. On the other hand, [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) can take arguments and can split on _any_ character you tell it to split upon. Furthermore, `split` doesn't have to split on _all_ choices but can be limited.

Answer (score 1):

`readlines` does platform agnostic line splitting and `split` does generic splitting.

As an example:

```
In [1]: from StringIO import StringIO

In [2]: StringIO('test:test:test').readlines()
Out[2]: ['test:test:test']

In [3]: StringIO('test:test:test').read().split(':')
Out[3]: ['test', 'test', 'test']
```